# How increase bad links scraping on web portal?

Tags: c#, parsing, web, web-scraping, https

I need to parse broken links (404 for example) on web portal. Its about 10.000 pages on portal and a lot of external links. I use HttpWebRequest in c# to download page html, then find all links in html and add already checked links in checked groop, and unchecked links queue for checking. I use multythreading, but it gives little advantage. 1 thread - 50 links per minute, 5 thread - 70. 
i think, my problem is the way i get html code. I use simple HttpWebRequest to get html:

`

```
string html;
HttpWebResponse response;
StreamReader respStream;
try
{
        HttpWebRequest reques = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link.ToString());
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0";
        request.Accept = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        respStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        html = respStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
respStream.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
        System.Console.WriteLine("-------------\n" +
                "Bad link: " + link + "\n" +
                "From: " + link.Parent +
                "\n" + ex.Message);
        link.ErrorComments = ex.Message;
        link.Parent.AddSon(link);
        continue;
}
normalLinks.Add(link);
```

`

My internet - 100mb/s. 1 page - 150-200 kb.
I need to increase speed in a few times. Anybody knows solution?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for posting a detailed question, showing what you have already tried! :)

Comment: Perhaps read only the header of the response instead of the full response?

Comment: i get only header, if link is external (not from main domain). But i need full response to parse html of internal page to find others links.

Answer (score 0):

Are a lot of your links going to the same domain? There is a limit to the number of concurrent connections to the same host. This can be overridden in app.config (assuming you're .net framework) [connection management max connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/connectionmanagement-element-network-settings)

Comment: Yes, same domain. But adding connections in config doesnt help.